# Cloud Dataflow - TextIO.Read: Return specific file URL given a match pattern

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

Given a match-pattern to a TextIO.Read (for instance gs://my_bucket/file-*.txt), I want to return the full URL of each and every matched file.
How can I retrieve this parameter?

Thanks

Comment: Is your data going to be the file paths?

Comment: Yes, a part of the ParDo transform I wish to do, is to add the file path to every processed object

Answer (score 4):

Dataflow doesn't currently support anything like this.

You can use GCS utilities to grab a list of files that match a given pattern with a *.

Here is their command line tool: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil
And some client libraries:
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/libraries#api-client-libraries

However note that if the files were written recently or change very often, GCS only guarantees eventual consistency on list operations. So you might grab a slightly different list each time. If the file list isn't changing, it should be correct.

Comment: Should I then read all the files one by one from this list using dataflow?

Comment: Is your only data the filenames? Or do you want the filename along with the data in the file? TextIO does not support this by default. Instead you can write a custom FileBasedSource/FileBasedSink for this or you can use Create.of(filenames) to generate a PCollection from the list of files. If you want to also read the files you can combine it with a ParDo.of(read all elements from file) to read the elements from each file.

Comment: I can actually start from reading a single file which is a list of about 200M file URLs. The question is - if I use this method, will this process be paralleled?

Comment: If you are just using the normal file sink (TextIO) this should be parallelized. It might not parallelize within a line, but can parallelize each line (and most likely a few lines together depending on size / number of workers).